# Cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe, Excel file generated in SAP Webi

Tags: excel, webi

I am working with `SAP BOBI 4.1`. My issue is when I export a `Webi` document to Excel, number fields are formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe, and dates are represented with only 2 digits for the year.

Formula in SAP Webi:

```
FormatNumber([obj];"#,#.00")
FormatDate(Max[obj]);"dd-Mmm-yy")
```

Please advise regarding this. Thank you.

1. Output from program:
   [image: Output from program]

   Expected output:
   [image: Expected output]
2. Output from program:
   [image: Output from program]

   Expected output:
   [image: Expected output]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ToNumber(FormatNumber([obj];"#,#.00"))
FormatDate(Max[obj]);"dd-Mmm-yyyy")
```

Comment: Hi @Toni. I try to use integrate your formula. It is fixed but I have a problem now with the decimal. 

output in program:
1

should be:
1.0000

Formula used:
ToNumber(FormatNumber([obj];"#.0000")

Please advise regarding this. Thank you.